# MVC SqlQuery and a 2nd sort

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am re-writing an existing legacy system that uses stored procedures to retrieve the data needed.

The new design will have the normal column sorting and text filtering, but I came across something that has me stumped.

I am able to perform a LINQ query on the retrieved data and get my desired result as follows:

```c#
var customerIDParam = new SqlParameter("@customerID", 452);

var result =
    db.Database.SqlQuery<InventoryDetail>("map_efs_InventoryDetail @customerID", customerIDParam).ToList();

// this works!
var finalResult1 = from s in result
                    .Where(s => s.cProductDescription.Contains("E"))
                    .OrderBy(s => s.cProductDescription)
                    select s;

return View(finalResult1.ToList());
```

I would really like to build the LINQ statement dynamically as follows BUT THIS FAILS, always returning the full query

```c#
var customerIDParam = new SqlParameter("@customerID", 452);

var result =
    db.Database.SqlQuery<InventoryDetail>("map_efs_InventoryDetail @customerID", customerIDParam).ToList();

// This does not work ???
var finalResult2 = from s in result select s;
finalResult2.OrderBy(s => s.cProductDescription);
finalResult2.Where(s => s.cProductDescription.Contains("E"));

return View(finalResult2.ToList());
```

If anyone can assist I would appreciate it.

Regards
Mark

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I discovered my own error.

```c#
var finalResult2 = from s in result select s;
finalResult2 = finalResult2.OrderBy(s => s.cProductDescription);
finalResult2 = finalResult2.Where(s => s.cProductDescription.Contains("E"));
return View(finalResult2.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

OrderBy/Where/Etc are "pure" methods, they will return an other IEnumerable, so your result never gets ordered or filtered, you  need to assign the new operations (I say operations beacuse IEnumerables have deferred execution), eg:

Assigning variables:

```
List<Customer> customers = context.Customers.ToList();
            IEnumerable<Company> companies = customers.Select(e => e.Company);
            IEnumerable<Company> companiesFiltered = companies.Where(e => e.Active);
            IOrderedEnumerable<Company> companiesOrdered = companiesFiltered.OrderBy(e => e.Id);
            companiesFiltered = companiesOrdered.ThenBy(e => e.Code); // because the variable and result are the same type we can do this
```

Using returning values:

```
var finalResult2 = result.Select(r => r.s)
.Where(s => s.cProductDescription.Contains("E"))
.OrderBy(s => s.cProductDescription);
```

Because every operation returns another IEnumrable we can "chain calls" fluently like that. Remember that actual execution takes place when you call ToList().

Comment: Hi Kondas, I think you missed my question. If I don't chain the calls, I get my expected results. If I chain them, I do not ...

Comment: Could you try my code?, on your posted code you aren't using the returning values of the functions you call